# Where is relationship between ldap group and linux group defined?

Tags: linux, ldap

For a given ldap group, how do I determine what linux groups are chosen for it? Is this relationship defined somewhere?

For instance, if I'm in the ldap group "admin", and in linux, I see I'm in the group "admin_users", where is the relationship between "admin" and "admin_users" defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, there are two main components which handle user accounts: the libc *nsswitch* framework looks up information, while PAM performs authentication. In other words, the nsswitch LDAP module is responsible for obtaining this information from LDAP and presenting it to the system.

Usually `objectClass: posixGroup` entries are translated directly to the corresponding OS group, but if any transformations were done, then they would be done by the nsswitch module as well.

There are a few different LDAP clients that can be used – *sssd* with libnss_sss, *nslcd* with libnss_ldap, Active Directory-specific Samba with libnss_winbind, and the obsolete standalone PADL libnss_ldap. Their configurations and features differ.

For example, *nslcd* can be configured to mangle any attribute (`map group cn ${cn}_users`), while *sssd* only has some predefined translations (like replacing spaces with dots). Check their corresponding manual pages – `nslcd.conf`, `sssd.conf`, `sssd-ldap`.

That said, I actually have some doubts that it's the same group. It could be that you're looking at two different LDAP entries – there are several kinds of "LDAP groups", some of which map to OS groups, while others don't. For example, there may be a `posixGroup` entry for Linux and a `groupOfNames` entry for LDAP's own purposes.

Answer (score -1):

In general you need to inspect the LDAP integration configuration in the OS. There, group filters and mappings are defined.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you!